# Why do sites regularly place language "en", "fr", etc in the URL rather than leaving it in a session variable/cookie etc?

Tags: session, url, cookies, web, internationalization

Surely language is an individual thing, and better set based on the user's browser settings or an explicit setting that they've selected and saved (via session/cookie).

If I'm sending a page I've just read to my french-speaking friend it would be better without any language code in the URL, so it opens in French for him based on his browser setting or on an earlier visit to the site.

This seems very obvious to me... but a LOT of major sites put the language in the URL.  So I feel I must be missing something...  What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantage I can see if for indexation purpose.  If your web site needs to be indexed (e-commerce products for instance) then the language become very important for regional search engines.

For instance here is an extract from [Google doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) :

> Google uses the content of the page to determine its language, but the
>   URL itself provides human users with useful clues about the page’s
>   content. For example, the following .ca URLs use fr as a subdomain or
>   subdirectory to clearly indicate French content:
>   [http://example.ca/fr/vélo-de-montagne.html](http://example.ca/fr/v%C3%A9lo-de-montagne.html) and
>   [http://fr.example.ca/vélo-de-montagne.html](http://fr.example.ca/v%C3%A9lo-de-montagne.html).